# Close and open html div in ng-template without breaking my code

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to close and open a new div in a ng-template element. When I try this my code breaks.

```
<div class="row">
   <ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-data [ngForOf]="dataArray">
      <app-user-dashboard-gauge [gaugeData]="data" class="col"></app-user-dashboard-gauge>
      <ng-template [ngIf]="i === 3">
         </div>
         <div class="row">
      </ng-template>
   </ng-template>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do this inside a ngFor to preserve my bootstrap rows. Does anyone know how to fix this or maybe another solution?

Edit: Ok I think I want that clear on what I wanted to happen. I update my code block and will try to explain it better. On the third iteration of my for loop I want the row div to be closed and a new one to open. And the rest of the `<app-user-dashboard-gauge>` to go in the second row div.

Comment: Hi! Can you show the entire code block, ngFor included?

Comment: you have closing div tag before `<div class="row">`, maybe this causes an issue

Comment: I updated the code block

Comment: The code is not correctly formatted (indentation) which makes it harder to read ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. So if the index is 3 you want to display one more ng-template, which would include a div? I don't think you can do it as you're trying to do since (I guess it's the error you're getting) you will be missing the closing tags for the first <ng-template> as long as the index is not 3...

Comment: I've set up a stackblitz cos I wanted to try things around. Maybe someone else can help you based on this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujrpvn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html (it does something, but I don't think it does what you want... as I said, I do not quite get it). The only thing I can think of is that maybe you could get around that with content projection, passing your index as input to your component and dealing with your extra code in the component itself? sounds rather complicated though.

Comment: No that isn't exactly what I meant. I want 3 of the app-user-dashboard-gauge components to be in the first div.row and the other 3 to be in the second div.row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. It might not be the best or the nicest looking but i split the incomming data into two parts and made another for loop for the secend group of data.

```
<div style="background-color: #202020">
  <div class="row">
    <ng-template ngFor let-data [ngForOf]="dataArray1">
        <app-user-dashboard-gauge [gaugeData]="data" class="col"></app-user-dashboard-gauge>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <ng-template ngFor let-data [ngForOf]="dataArray2">
        <app-user-dashboard-gauge [gaugeData]="data" class="col"></app-user-dashboard-gauge>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Im still open for feedback if someone knows a better solution but this fix will suffice for now.

Comment: I think this is the best approach...if you have an array that should be rendered in two different containers depending on its size, just divide it in two different arrays! But shouldn't you also use an ngIf on the second container? If there's not enough elements on the original array, you'll still render an empty second div.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="i !== 3">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I don't want to open and close I want to close and open